# TeXnicCenter, don't execute viewer

Tags: texniccenter

In TeXnicCenter, is there someway to define a Build Profile that doesn't execute a viewer, just compiles?

I'm using the super awesome Sumatra pdf reader that updates whenever the pdf file changes. I don't need to execute a viewer. Executing it is annoying because when it's done it steals the focus from me and I find myself typing into air, thinking I'm still focused on TeXniCenter.

If I clear all execution instructions on *Build > Define Output Profiles 
> Viewer* I get `Could not execute command.` error message from TeXnicCenter, which is also annoying. How could I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TeXnic Center toolbar, the second icon is `Build current file` (shortcut `Ctrl + F7`), while the sixth is `Build and view current file` (shortcut `Shift + Ctrl + F5`:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your right. I was afraid I was missing something silly like that.. :S  Thank you anyway.